# LUIS resource key disabled in Language Understanding Portal

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I've a payed azure subscription and defined a LUIS resource in West Europe region.
If I log in to Language Understanding portal and try to assign the resource to my LUIS app, once I've selected tenant and subscription my resource key appears grayed with the message: "Not applicable in this domain".
What does that mean ? Can I only use west US LUIS enpoints for my web application configured in west europe ? what I'm missing here ?

Thanks for help

Comment: Are you using eu.luis.ai for setting up your LUIS app? Along with that, make sure you are using the same account that you are using when logging into your Azure portal. 

Please find more info here on boundaries and regions:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-reference-regions

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-boundaries

Comment: Thank you Dana V for your comment. This solved the issue. I was mislead by the link in the quickstart page of LUIS resource in azure portal. There, even if the endpoint for resource correctly reported westeurope as region for the application enpoint, the link for the portal points directly to www.luis.ai and not eu.luis.ai. Just created an new app there and everything works as expected

Comment: Great, glad that helped.

Comment: For me, it was only disabled after I changed to the "new experience". Going back to the old UI enabled the button again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The region in which you publish your LUIS app corresponds to the region or location you specify in the Azure portal when you create an Azure LUIS endpoint key.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-reference-regions